# Check an if statement against an array

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to save some information from textbox controls that have been dynamically created and may have been deleted since their creation. I can provide an array of strings that match a number already being used to save that data to match my list of deleted against. essentially to prevent exceptions from being thrown I need to not try and save data from the deleted textboxes. Here is what I am working with atm:

```
int TextboxNumber = 0;
for (int pc = 0; pc < Int32.Parse(PrinterCount.Text); pc++)
{
    for (int r = 0; r <= 2; r++)
    {
        TextboxNumber = pc * 3 + r;
        if (TextboxNumber != Int32.Parse(deleted[]))
        {
            TextboxName = "textBox" + TextboxNumber.ToString();
            printerinfo = printerinfo + this.Controls[TextboxName].Text + ",";
        }
    }

    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        w.WriteLine(printerinfo);
    };
    printerinfo = "";
}
```

You can see on Line 6 is where I have this if statement. The deleted[] array can be any series of three numbers such as 0,1,3 or 7,8,9 , or both or more... How would one validate in this situation?

Comment: Generally, if you are dealing with user entered numbers, you should assume the user is likely to make a typing error.  Consider using `int.TryParse` to get the numeric value of `PrinterCount.Text` before you get to the loop. Your question would be **much** better if you included a declaration (and a typical initialization) of `deleted[]`.  I'm assuming it is `string [] delete;` (i.e., not a _series of three numbers..._).  Create another array (of `int[]`) from `deleted[]` (using, for example, `.Select`) and then use `Array.Contains`

Comment: `Int32.Parse(deleted[])` is nonsense; what are you hoping it will do? (This entire approach seems hard work; tell us more of the surrounding detail so we can suggest something easier)

Comment: It will always be a series of three numbers that is why I stated it that way the user is not entering the numbers they are being fed by a delete function then split into the array for this function It is removing the textboxes that contain the details about a printer connection. Although barbaric functional so in this function when it saves the details to a file it needs to not attempt to save the data from those text boxes as they no longer exist. I create the textboxes dynamically in another function with a standard naming convention the last character of which is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for any who come after; on line 6 put

```
if (checkdeleted(TextboxNumber))
```

then create this function

```
bool checkdeleted(int number)
        {
            string[] deleted = Deleted.Text.Split(',');
            if (deleted.Count() != 1)
            {
                for (int c = deleted.Count() - 2; c >= 0; c--)
                {
                    if (Int32.Parse(deleted[c]) == number)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Thank you very much me!